# Record screen in real time using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, real-time

I am using an optical microscope and camera to record some videos which are post-processed in MATLAB.

Real time acquisition and pixel statistics would be extremely helpful, because some of what I am looking at absorbs very little light (I am using transmission mode). An example is that a blank (background) sample would give me an an average pixel value across a 512x512 ccd array of something like 144 (grayscale). An actual sample might have an average value of 140 or so. This subtle shift in pixel intensity would be useful in helping me focus the microscope.

Unfortunately, my camera setup is not supported by MATLAB, so I cannot use the image acquisition toolbox for real time. So I was wondering, is there a way that I could 'fake' real time image acquisition by selecting say a rectangle of my current desktop (the rectangle that is the video output of the microscopes camera), for matlab to record in real time?

Thanks

Comment: What model camera is it?  Is there a reason that you need to capture data through MATLAB and not capture in one program then post-process in MATLAB?

Comment: Hi. The camera is connected to the computer by a euresys frame grabber card, which I don't think MATLAB supports. The reason I want to capture it in real time is to ensure I am focused on the correct spot in the sample. You are right in saying I can post-process it in MATLAB, but often the post processing tells me whether it was captured correctly in the first place.

Comment: It may not, but there looks to be an API available for it. Those calls probably can be made from within MATLAB. That might be a place to start.